# Save (same) permalink from wp-cli

Tags: migration, wp-cli

I moved many WordPress sites to a new server and all permalinks need to be "refreshed". I need to save again (without any changes) settings->permalinks to resolve pages/posts 404 error.

I ask if it exists a way to save permalinks (without changes) from wp-cli.

I Know:

**wp rewrite structure**

but the structure of the permalinks must be passed as a parameter and each site has a different one and I need only to save with the same settings.

It's possible?

Answer (score 2):

To re-save the current permalink structure with wp-cli.

1. Get the current permalink structure first by running:

`wp option get permalink_structure`

Copy the results.

2. Save the wanted permalink structure with:

`wp rewrite structure '/%postname%'`

Where `/%postname%` is the output of the first command.

Answer (score 0):

If you wan't to refresh it, you can just use `wp rewrite flush`.

Source: https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/rewrite/flush/